# Should this be comment or answer?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/59838/8019) was converted to [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/shorter-sarcastic-way-to-express-the-cook-must-have-made-a-mistake#comment114125_59838), and I don't really see why.  It gave a specific answer to the question posed, and speculated that, if this is really what is being asked, it may be off-topic.  It may be just me, but that seems, more than most posts, an answer rather than a comment.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It has happened to me, too.  Maybe it is done automatically when an answer is short?

Comment: @GEdgar Nope, it's a moderator action. The auto-conversion comes into play when you post a third answer to the same question, as far as I know.

Comment: I added the link to the comment. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember if I acted on a flag or just converted it myself, but that doesn't really matter anyway. Your answer literally says,

> there are so many possiblilities that this is off-topic here, unless you can cut it down. Maybe writers.se?

If a question is off-topic, you are kind of expected to vote to close it as such. If a question belongs on Writers, you are kind of expected to vote to migrate it there. In any case such "meta" commentary just does not belong in an answer. That's precisely what comments are there for. And frankly, at well over 7k rep you are kind of expected to know all that. :-)

Comment: Agreed. The question was no good anyway, so imho it shouldn't have gotten *any* answers. At most, as a courtesy to the OP, one might provide an answer in a comment - while voting to close, and perhaps explaining to the OP *why* his question isn't a good one for the site. So converting Tim's answer to a comment is fine; he should have posted it as such in the first place (as should every other answerer, but I'll just fight one battle at a time here! :)

Answer (score 3):

The speculation part was really a comment. I probably would've converted it as well. In that part you were not answering, but commenting.

Concerning the rest, I wouldn't say you were specific, rather *very concise*. You didn't give any explanation regarding your proposed expression. Perhaps providing some elaboration would've changed the moderator decision, so that you would have had an edit, rather than a conversion.